# How to make Spark-submit in linux

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to build a package with Spark on Linux, following the below instructions:

> Command to build executable jar:
>
> 1. Navigate to the base location of our project in cmd prompt
> 2. Execute `sbt package`
> 3. Executable jar will be created in the following path: `<project path>\target\scala-2.11`

I am getting the error:

```
bash: sbt: command not found
```

I was able to build jar in windows machine, but am unable to create a project package on Linux.

Comment: Check the installation instructions [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Installing-sbt-on-Linux.html)

Comment: Thanks. But i see below error -                                                               sudo: apt-get: command not found

Comment: Hey Grisha... thanks ! That link helped me

Answer (score 1):

You need to install sbt package on your linux machine. Please follow below steps to install sbt:
Run the following shell commands:

wget http://apt.typesafe.com/repo-deb-build-0002.deb

sudo dpkg -i repo-deb-build-0002.deb

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install sbt

If you again see sbt is not on your path. Try to run ./sbt from ~/bin/sbt/bin or wherever the sbt executable is to verify that it runs correctly. Also check that you have execute permissions on the sbt executable. If this works , then add ~/bin/sbt/bin to your path and sbt should run from anywhere.

Then follow below steps to create jar file:
1. Under your project folder put your .scala file into source folder.
Project->Source->.scala

2. Create a .sbt file and add all the dependencies of your project like maven is having dependencies on pom.xml
3. Run the command sbt-clean;sbt-package 
   This will download all the dependencies and create a jar file under 'target' folder

Comment: Thanks Khushbu - but i see this error 'sudo: dpkg: command not found' . Any idea to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

This error is because you have dpkg is missing from your system. If such a thing were possible, you couldn't download and install dpkg without dpkg!

There is another solution,use below commands to install sbt without running .deb file

$ curl https://bintray.com/sbt/rpm/rpm | sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/bintray-sbt-rpm.repo

$ sudo yum install sbt

Check the path is set correctly using below command and output should be like that:

$ which sbt
/usr/bin/sbt

if not ,then add ~/bin/sbt/bin to your path and sbt should run from anywhere.

Lastly, to verify sbt is working try running sbt -help or likewise. The output with -help will look something like this:

$ sbt -help
Usage: sbt [options]

-h | -help         print this message
  ...